# Is there a way to selectively sync photos?

Tags: sync, camera, photos, google-plus, google-plus-photos

I find the idea that all of my photos, no matter in which folder should automatically be synced to G+ a bit ridiculous.

Is there a way to only sync a certain folder/album? I'm mainly interested in syncing my camera roll.

Comment: Is your question restricted to G+? There I don't know of any solution, but I could name you some for e.g. Dropbox, Box, or other cloud services. I'm not familiar with G+: in case the cloud service behind that is identical with *Google Drive*, I would know some solutions as well :)

Comment: @Izzy, I'd like it to be this default G+ Photos app sync, but it can be something else. Preferably Google Drive since that's what I use.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, yannbane! On that condition, please see my answer I've just posted. For a full list of supported cloud services, just follow the link to the app's description. I'm pretty happy with the full version, using it for quite a while now.

Answer (score 3):

Launch G+ Photos app. Swipe right on the left edge to open up the menu. Go to "On Device". You can select which folders to be synced by tapping on the cloud icon on the right of the folder name.

Note: You have to turn on "Back up local folders" option in settings. Initially, all folders will be synced and you can  selectively turn off for each folder in the "On Device" section.

Comment: Nice solution with no 3rd party! Is there any way to prevent them from showing up at all? I don't really want to see album covers and friends' profile pictures in Google Photos.

Comment: I don’t see a way of *creating* folders here though. So this would lead me to share the “Camera” folder which is precisely what I don’t want to do — am I overlooking something? Note that since this answer was written, a new release of the Photos app was pushed that changed the whole interface. So maybe it used to be possible?

Comment: I just tried creating another folder with photos in it and enabling backup. It allows me to turn on/off sync for other folders but the "Camera" folder can't be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

As *Google Drive* is an option to the OP: I use an app called [FolderSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/foldersync/dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full), which support a load of cloud services (including e.g. *Google Drive*, *Amazon S3*, and *Dropbox*) as well as FTP/SFTP/FTPS to support your own servers. Using it successfully with SFTP and Dropbox, I can recommend its use:

- you can define "Folder Pairs" to sync, e.g. a single remote directory and the corresponding local directory. Subdirectories can be included optionally
- you can trigger the sync manually, or define automatic sync schedules. Instand upload should be possible as well, though I didn't try that yet.
- the paid version supports [tasker](/questions/tagged/tasker), which gives you increased flexibility. As to my experience (a while ago with some previous version, so this behaviour might have changed meanwhile) *FolderSync*'s internal scheduler causes a device wakeup all 5min regardless of the sync schedule chosen, I prefer triggering syncs via *Tasker*.

So with *Google Drive* being acceptable, you could use *FolderSync* to define a specific folder pair, and thus sync only those folder(s) you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Camera Album](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.las.cameraalbum). This app automatically redirects captured photos to the selected album/directory. You can have multiple albums and quickly  switch between them before taking photo.
And with  applications mentioned in previous posts  you can synchronize only directories that you want.

Comment: Do you have any affiliation with this app?

Comment: Yes, I tested the application about 14 days before its publication (non-public alpha version).

Answer (score 1):

On my phone running the latest stable version of Google+, only the camera roll is auto backup'd. There are several additional folders (downloads, Path, Instagram) that are not being synced. From your description, G+ currently does exactly what you want.

Comment: Are you sure that it's the intended behavior? Please see [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/59197/which-photos-get-automatically-backed-up-to-g) if so.

Comment: AFAIK it's currently the indented behaviour but I haven't found any documentation of it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no way to selectively sync photos with G+. But on Dropbox, by default only the camera roll photos are uploaded by default for cloud backup.

Comment: That's kind of horrible, I don't understand why would they do this. *"We don't want people to use our services!"*

Comment: @jco Because automatically telling whether image X is a photo or something else isn't easy, and typical users probably have non-photo images in more places than they have photos.

Answer (score 0):

**Still looking for other answers**

I've found [Gallery Drive Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gallery.cloud.sync&hl=en), an app that will selectively sync image folders when you want it to, *not automatically* (you have to go in and press "sync" next to the gallery for it to work). This can be a feature, but in my case it isn't since I'd like it to happen automatically.