# Which photos get automatically backed up to G+

Tags: sync, google-plus, google-plus-photos

When using the G+ Auto Backup feature, do only my camera photos get backed up? What about downloaded photos, those that I create, or the ones that I transfer from PC to my phone via USB?

The [support page](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1647509?hl=en) and the Photos app seem to be unclear about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I have read, the only photos that are backed up are those in the folder named "DCIM/Camera", which should include photos from your camera. If you move other photos there (e.g. downloaded, etc.), they should be backed up.